# Reference is not checking exact type

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I defined a model as mentioned below:

```
var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
askedBy: {type:ObjectId, Ref:'User'},
relatedCourses: [
    {type: ObjectId, ref:'Course'}
]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema, 'Questions')
```

(Because of a bug) At the time of saving/creating new document of type Question, relatedCourses field is assigned to an array of object ids other than 'Course', and mongoose didn't produce any error, and saved the document.

It took sometime to dig and find this error.

My question is, why mongoose not checking exact Schema type? What is the need of mentioning 'Course' in ref field when any ObjectId is sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found mongoose-id-validator, which is doing the required type validation.